# Where do I get the actual codes of FOAF vocabularies?

Tags: rdfs, foaf

The page http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/ discusses the FOAF vocabularies. Details of the terms are discussed in the same page (e.g. http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Person).

But if I am looking for the actual `rdfs` code of a class or property, where do I get it?

Surprisingly, a web search has not produced anything. The textbooks contain some class
and property codes, but they are mostly outdated, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header of http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/, there are links to the various versions, including links to RDF/XML serializations, e.g. currently:

> **This version:**
>   http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20140114.html ([rdf](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20140114.rdf))
>
> **Latest version:**
>   http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/ ([rdf](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf))
>
> **Previous version:**
>   http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20100809.html ([rdf](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20100809.rdf))

As explained in the "Status of This Document" section, you can also get the RDF/XML document via content negotiation:

> An RDF/XML encoding of the specification is available by direct link or by HTTP content negotiation from the [namespace URI](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/).

And some parts are included in the HTML via RDFa:

> The HTML specification no longer embeds the RDF/XML markup; however an experimental subset of the RDF is included in this document using RDFa notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow did not notice that the word `rdf` constitutes a separate link. Feel like a fool. Still keeping the question because this *may be* beneficial to others.